# how to append input fields using push() function in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating add more field functionality in angularjs. I am using below code

Javascript

```
 <script>
   function FruitsController($scope){
        var div = 'Apple';            
        $scope.fruits=[];
        $scope.addFruit=function(){
          $scope.fruits.push(div);
        }
    } 

 <script>
```

HTML

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">{{fruit}}</li></ul>
<button ng-click="addFruit()">Add</button>
```

Above code works successfully and appends 'Apple' string in body. But I want to append input type text field like string. So I am using below script that does not works.

```
      <script>
       function FruitsController($scope){
            var div = '<input type="text">';            
            $scope.fruits=[];
            $scope.addFruit=function(){
              $scope.fruits.push(div);
            }
        } 

     <script>
```

I know above my code is totally wrong. Please give me some ideo that how to add input type in angularjs

Comment: Do you want to add only a single input, or any number of them? What's their purpose?

Comment: I want to add number of input fields

Comment: Dont try to push html element like div in angularjs scope. Instead add model and that will render the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render UI element in html. **Your HTML looks like**

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
              <input ng-model="fruit">
      </li>
   </ul>
   <button ng-click="addFruit()">Add</button>
```

Your **controller** looks like

```
<script>
       function FruitsController($scope){
            var fruit = 'apple';            
            $scope.fruits=[];
            $scope.addFruit=function(){
              $scope.fruits.push(fruit);
            }
        } 

<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
        <input ng-model="fruit">
    </li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="addFruit()">Add</button>
```

Keep your UI/HTML code in your HTML template, keep pure data structures in your controller. Through Angular's two-way data binding, `ng-model` will directly update your entries in `$scope.fruits` when your input changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. For input text boxes you need to use ng-model attribute as it is two way data binding.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
        <input type="text" ng-model="fruit">
    </li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="addFruit()">Add</button>
```